Entity Framework putting random GUID into a string.Empty field at database save
I've created a full EF hook to one of our databases (that I do not control the structure of) to do some basic CRUD operations. So far, everything has gone fine. However, I'm running into an issue with the insert of one of my classes. It's trying to insert a new record into a table called 'applmort'. I won't go too far into how that database table is designed, since it's not my company that creates it. But we have access to it and can do CRUD operations to it.
This table has a column I'll call UWT that is declared as a varchar(12). So, I set up the EF configuration to limit the values going into this to 12. You'll notice this in the 'config' file I'll post. While the column is NOTNULL, I can simply put in a blank varchar into the column and everything is fine. No table constraints on that.
So, when I try to add a new record, I do not specify this field in the object. I can do this with a bunch of other columns in the table, and since my config file tells EF to insert a string.Empty as the default, everything works out cozy. Except for this UWT column. It balks and tells me that there's a truncation error. Since I'm putting an empty string in, that seems weird. I dig down and realize that EF is attempting to create this UWT column as an alternate key, then filling it with a random GUID that I never told it to use. I track this down down and find that I have another table connected to this one via config file (should be the second config class I listed below). This other object is linking to my Application object through the UWT. That should be normal, and I didn't think putting this in would cause an issue. However, it is. When I remove the 'one-to-many' from the second object to break the link, the record inserts correctly.
Another work-around I found was to specify the UWT column on the Application object as a blank string before it hits the default in the config. This also allows the record to be inserted without issue.
I could use either of these workarounds. The second would work the best and allow me to keep my table link. But this seems very, very strange. This doesn't happen with any other table link that I'm creating, so I have to ask: am I doing something wrong here? Did I set something somewhere that is causing a GUID to get shoved into a very obviously non-GUID column? I can't, for the life of me, find this.
public class Application
{
    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ApplicationDate { get; set; }
    public string StructureID { get; set; } = null!;
    public string UWT { get; set; } = null!;
    public int UnitNumber { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Structure Structure { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationHold> ApplicationHolds { get; set; } = [];
}

public class ApplicationHold
{
    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }
    public string UWT { get; set; } = null!;
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class ApplicationConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Application> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable("applmort");

        entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);

        entity.Property(e => e.ChangeDate)
            .HasColumnName("changedate")
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now)
            .IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.ID)
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .UseIdentityColumn();
        entity.Property(e => e.ApplicationDate)
            .HasColumnName("appldate")
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
        entity.Property(e => e.StructureID)
            .HasColumnName("stru")
            .HasMaxLength(3)
            .HasDefaultValue(string.Empty)
            .IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.UWT)
            .HasColumnName("uwt")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(12)
            .HasDefaultValue(string.Empty)
            .IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.UnitNumber)
            .HasColumnName("units")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .HasDefaultValue(0)
            .IsRequired();

        entity.HasOne(e => e.Structure).WithMany(e => e.Applications)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.LoanStructureID)
            .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.LoanStructureID)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}

public class ApplicationHoldConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationHold>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationHold> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable("applhold");

        entity.HasKey(e => e.ID);

        entity.Property(e => e.ChangeDate)
            .HasColumnName("changedate")
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now)
            .IsRequired();
        entity.Property(e => e.ID)
            .HasColumnName("id")
            .UseIdentityColumn();
        entity.Property(e => e.UWT)
            .HasColumnName("uwt")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(12)
            .HasDefaultValue(string.Empty)
            .IsRequired();

        entity.HasOne(entity => entity.Application).WithMany(e => e.ApplicationHolds)
            .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.UWT)
            .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.UWT)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}


EF is trying to make a unique constraint on the field UWT by maybe how it understands the relation between Application and ApplicationHold
You can try not using HasDefaultValue(string. Empty) since it seems that even having this code is enough to make EF auto-generate for a relationship, and erase the default value configurations and handle them in your application.
entity.Property(e => e.UWT)
            .HasColumnName("uwt")
            .HasColumnType("varchar")
            .HasMaxLength(12)
            .HasDefaultValue(string.Empty) 
            .IsRequired();

Setting this value directly should fix the issue for you when inserting the record
Application application = new()
{
    UWT = string.Empty, 
};


Yeah, this seems to be a good fix for it.  It's still weird, though, since I have a bunch of other table links and string.Empty set for a bunch of other places...why it's this one is a mystery.  But thanks!  That's a good way to handle it.
If anyone else  knows WHY this is happening...I'd like to know.
